# Ubuntu 10.04 with HD flash

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, flash, nvidia-ion, vdpau

Just noticed that 10.04 is out.  My media server has been packed away for a few months but I might dust if off and give 10.04 a shot but I thought I'd see if anyone has any success stories with HD flash in either Chrome or Firefox.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 9.10 and it was a large enough pain to get VDPAU working with my Zotac Ion-ITX-C board (eventually found an mplayer PPA that had it compiled in)

From reading the 10.04 docs it looks like this is standard now, but I'm wondering about streaming HD, from, say flash or Divx.  I've never been able to get HD flash to play without it being extremely choppy, and I chalk this up to the lack of hardware assisted decoding like VDPAU (a guess).

My board certainly isn't a competitor in CPU power or memory, which is why i've needed the HW accelerated decoding for HD vids in the past.

Just wondering if anyone has had any success stories playing HD vid online (flash, divx or what have you)

Answer (score 1):

Playing HD videos through Flash works fine for me both for YouTube 720P and Vimeo HD. YouTube 1080P stutters though.

Answer (score 1):

Playing Youtube 720p crashed my Flash 10 in Google Chrome (Xubuntu 10.04)

1080P MKV video doesn't work for me but I think thats because my computer can't read the file fast enough. It does this with VLC in Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 on the same machine.

720P MKV video works fine.

You may have to wait for Flash 10.1 to come out before you get streaming high def flash goodness.

BTW, using Lenovo T400 w/ Intel C2D P8400 @ 2.26 GHz, 2GB ram, ATI 3470 video card, and 7200 RPM hard drive.